# Start a storyboard view in UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to programmatically start a UIView in a UITabBarController in a different storyboard file.

In `WelcomeVC.swift`, it has no UITabBar and lives in `Main.storyboard`. It calls the UITabBar ViewController when a UIButton is clicked

```
@objc func startMatching(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Test", bundle: nil)
    let pdv = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AVC") as! AVC
    self.present(pdv, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In `Test.storyboard`, it contains 1 UITabBarController and 2 view controllers: `AVC` and `BVC`. They both function as intended if we call present() on them, but the UITabBar doesn't show up.

How do I get the tab controller to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to present the `UITabBarViewController`, give it a storyboard identifier and present it, not present `AVC` directly

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Test", bundle: nil)
let pdv = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController") as! UITabBarViewController
self.present(pdv, animated: true, completion: nil)
```